# ¿Qué significado tiene “una de... que”? "Tengo una de trabajo que no tengo tiempo libre"

Tags: gramática, locuciones

¿Cómo es que se usa “una” y no “uno” en esta frase?

> Tengo **una de** trabajo **que** no tengo un minuto libre.

A mi entender el nombre tiene que corresponder al nombre.

Comment: Ya he respondido pero de todas formas tengo curiosidad, ¿de dónde sacaste esta frase? ¿Es de un libro o la escuchaste? Siempre es recomendable aclarar de dónde proviene la frase porque puede ser dialectal.

Comment: Favor adicionar a la pregunta la fuente en donde encontró la frase. El contexto es muy importante para poder dar una respuesta más certera

Answer (score 5):

En *tengo una de trabajo que...* hay una elipsis (omisión de un elemento que se deja implícito). Aunque no se puede decir con seguridad, probablemente *una* significa *una cantidad* en este caso. Por el tono con el que se pronuncia esta clase de oraciones, se interpreta que

> *Tengo una (cantidad) de trabajo que no tengo un minuto libre.*

equivale a

> *Tengo tal cantidad de trabajo que no tengo un minuto libre.*

Esta clase de elipsis (con *una* = *una/tal cantidad*) siempre se utiliza con el mismo patrón que *tal / tan / tanto... que..*, y generalmente lo que sigue es algo negativo. Por ejemplo:

- *Le dieron una de golpes que no se podía levantar del piso.* (= *Le dieron tantos golpes que...*)
- *En el campo había una de ovejas que era imposible contarlas.* (= *En el campo había tantas ovejas que...*)

Esta clase de expresión es bastante coloquial, propia del idioma hablado informal, seguramente de algunas regiones pero no de todas, y a mí me suena además un poco anticuada.

Answer (score 0):

> Tengo *una* de *trabajo* que no tengo un minuto libre.

En el ejemplo que citas la correspondencia que esperas de género no se da con la palabra **trabajo** (masculino) sino con la palabra implícita a la que **una** alude (pudiendo referir a distintas cosas de género femenino (la coma es necesaria)

> Tengo *una* [**cantidad** / **montaña** / **pila**] de trabajo, que no tengo un minuto libre

Es una forma que se verifica bastante en el lenguaje hablado y coloquial, porque permite una amplitud de sentidos

> *Le descubrieron **una**, que ni te cuento...*

Esta frase se podría escuchar perfectamente en una conversación, al menos de  Argentina o Uruguay, como prolegómeno o inicio al recuento de algo (sobre esa tal***cosa*** —grave, suculenta, jugosa— referible con chismosa fruición).

También se encuentran ejemplos escritos, como [aquí](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=o3zoDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT34&dq=%22una+que+ni+te+cuento%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw3uWhwsTlAhXXLLkGHXy2BlEQ6AEISDAD#v=onepage&q=%22una%20que%20ni%20te%20cuento%22&f=false) o [aquí](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=e6VAAAAAYAAJ&q=%22una+que+ni+te+cuento%22&dq=%22una+que+ni+te+cuento%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw3uWhwsTlAhXXLLkGHXy2BlEQ6AEIUjAE)

Aquí hay [otra explicación](https://letralia.com/ed_let/lenguaje/3.htm) sobre este modismo (**una que ...**)

[image: frase "una que ni te cuento"]